# How to read a Spanish encoded file and store it character by character?

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8, wchar-t, wstring

I have trouble reading a file and storing it on memory since it is written in Spanish, I think it could be an encoding problem. I would like to know a way to print or store each of the characters separately. I have already tried many things but the most accurate approach I have found is using the method `wstring readFile(const char* filename)`,as showed in the code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

std::wstring readFile(const char* filename)//Read using a file using wifstream
{
    std::wifstream wif(filename);

    std::wstringstream wss;

    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring fileContent = readFile("read.txt"); //Read file to wstring.

    std::wcout << fileContent ; //Print the wstring. This works fine.
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;//Give spacing.

    wchar_t a; //create variable wchar_t.
    int fs = fileContent.size();
    std::cout << "Number of chars: " << fs; //Check content size.

    for (int i = 0; i < fs; i++){ //I want to print each letter.

        a = fileContent.at(i);  //Assign to "a" content of specified index.

        std::wcout << " " << a ; //Print character stored in variable a.
    }
}
```

It seems there is a problem when storing or printing the value of `fileContent.at(i)` or `fileContent[i]` in the variable `wchar_t a`. Do you know what could be improved in the code or give me a guideline to solve this problem?

I am using Macintosh and Linux, if it helps to know.
Thanks!

Comment: "character by character" is never meaningful in Unicode. You should avoid `wchar_t` entirely and use utf-8 encoded `char` containers, then use separate APIs depending on whether you want to count bytes, code units, code points, columns, graphemes, or grapheme clusters.

Comment: `It seems there is a problem` So, what is the problem? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ?

Comment: So the problem is that expected an outcome in the console, in order to see what string is stored in the `wchar_t  a `  variable. As an example, I would expect to see an accented i as í in the console, but I just got: ??.

Comment: Looking into the value stored in memory (with help of an IDE) I just figured out that the problem is only given when the value of the string tries to be displayed in the console, since in memory things are working in a correct way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `std::wifstream`, which returns Unicode characters using `wchar_t` (UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on platform), but you are not telling `std::wifstream` what the encoding of the source file is so that it can decode the file data from Spanish to Unicode.  You need to [`imbue()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) an appropriate Spanish locale into the `std::wifstream` before you can start reading the file data.